# Computer Vision API - v1.0 Recognize Handwritten Text returns empty response

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to start using the computer vision API but I keep getting an empty response. My request in php (as exported by Postman) looks like this:

```
<?php
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/recognizeText');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);
$request->setQueryData(array(
  'language' => 'en',
  'handwriting' => 'true'
));

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'Postman-Token' => '442d04f7-49a0-4262-9d0f-666fe5240cc7',
  'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
  'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
  'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'KEY'
));

try {
  $response = $request->send();
  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

The above code works fine with the ocr endpoint!

The file is passed as binary using Postman.

Edit: I also tried to copy/paste the code from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/php#ocr-php-example-request and if I change the ocr endpoint to recognizeText I get an empty response as well!

Comment: Have you tried putting `?handwriting=true` at the end of the URL to see if that helps?

Comment: `The file is passed as binary using Postman.` where is the equivalent in PHP code?

Comment: @Jon Yes if you see the setQueryData method handwriting is set to true.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari the code is generated by Postman. The file is selected in a file input field. The same code works for ocr endpoint though, so the problem is not there I believe!

Comment: I also tried to copy/paste the code from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/php#ocr-php-example-request and if I change the ocr endpoint to recognizeText I get an empty response as well!

Comment: I don't understand, are you trying to mimic the Postman request in PHP code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the other Computer Vision endpoints, `RecognizeText` is an asynchronous operation.  Barring some issue with the image, you will get a 202 response instead of the usual 200 response.  202 responses customarily contain an empty response body.  In this particular case you can find the URL where you can query for completion of the task.  The documentation is [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200).  The header you're looking for is `Operation-Location`.